# Observe closeable with default methods

Tags: java

I want to extend the Closeable-Interface so that I can add Listeners, that get notificated when the resource is closed.

The CloseListener-API is rather simple and straight forward:

```
public interface CloseListener {
  public void objectWillBeClosed(CloseableObservable closeable);
  public void objectClosed(CloseableObservable closeable);
}
```

I found a [nasty trick](https://javax0.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/how-not-to-use-java-8-default-methods/) in a blog, that uses Java8's default methods to recreate multiple inheritance and I asked myself if it might be valid to try it for an Observable-Interface:

```
public interface CloseableObservable extends Closeable{

    class HiddenAndNasty{
        private static final Map<CloseableObservable, Collection<CloseListener>> allObservers = new WeakHashMap<>();

        private static final Collection<CloseListener> getObservers(CloseableObservable observable){
            synchronized (observable) {
                Collection<CloseListener> observers = allObservers.get(observable);
                if(observers == null){
                    observers = new ArrayList<>();
                    allObservers.put(observable, observers);
                }
                return observers;
            }
        }
    }

    public default void addObserver(CloseListener observer){
        HiddenAndNasty.getObservers(this).add(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public default void close() throws IOException{
        // Copy Collection to avoid concurrent modification
        Collection<CloseListener> observers = new ArrayList<>(HiddenAndNasty.getObservers(this));
        observers.forEach(observer -> observer.objectWillBeClosed(this));
        closeInternal();
        observers.forEach(observer -> observer.objectClosed(this));
    }

    /** not part of the public api, use close() instead */
    void closeInternal() throws IOException;

}
```

This seems to work - here is a simple example, that works:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestAutoCloseableOnObservableCloseable {

    public static class SomeCloseableClass implements CloseableObservable{

        @Override
        public void closeInternal() throws IOException{
            System.out.println("Now I close myself");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try(SomeCloseableClass someObject = new SomeCloseableClass()){
            someObject.addObserver(new CloseListener() {
                @Override
                public void objectWillBeClosed(CloseableObservable closeable) {
                    System.out.println("Object will be closed!");
                }
                @Override
                public void objectClosed(CloseableObservable closeable) {
                    System.out.println("Object was closed!");
                }
            });
        }// try-with-resource

    }   // main
}
```

It works - but it seems somehow evil to me. Very evil. Is it an [Anti-Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AntiPattern.html)?

Comment: My first question "what for"? If you want to observe random close methods, then using Aspect4J to wrap an aspect around that method would be trivial - even possible with spring aop, if your objects are spring managed. As for your code: Your method only work for classes you can alter, you could as easily create a, let's call it "OberverManager" which does all the work for your observing, preventing you from having to inherit the logic, allowing you to do it via composition. All in all I simply don't see the need to abuse the default method here.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz to observe (for example) closing of resources I create. I never heard of Aspect4J. I'll definetly have a look at it. Thanks for the hint.